# django rest framework view with merged results from different object serializers

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

having the following models

```
class TreeLifephase(DBordered):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class TreeWidth(DBordered):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

and many more like this, that contain editable attributes of my `Tree` objects. For a select field on the UI I want to have all available treelifephases and treewidths with one query - to have a json result that looks something like

```
{
    "treelifephases": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "young"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "medium"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "old"
        }
    ],
    "treewidths": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "10-20cm"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "21-30cm"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "31-40cm"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have serializers for the Models at hand and it would be awesome to have a view that could just get a list of serializers to return a resultset like the above.

Comment: You can use SerializerMethodFields to generate custom fields, I tend to use different Serializers for Entry generation and entry representation.

Comment: I see what you mean, but how would i get a view then, seems like that always needs a queryset (of one type?)

Comment: put differently: my problem seems to be to make a viewset that can distinguish between defferent models in the `queryset` or is there a different way I am not seeing here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SerializerMethodField` and you need to create a model, in order to use model serializer.

```
class FullTree(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    full_tree =  serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
          model = FullTreeModel
          fields = ('treewidth','lifephase')



    get_full_tree(obj):
       treewidth = obj.treewidths # get all your treewidth
       lifephase = obj.lifephases# get all your lifephases
       //build your tree with your serializers
       return your_full_tree
```

Comment: how would the viewset's `queryset` value be with your mastertree serializer? do I not need the `FullTreeModel` there?

Comment: @user9 it just a simple serializer, you init it passing your instances tree.

Comment: yeah, but what i want is not the tree's treewidth and lifephase, but ALL treewidths and lifephases that are available. sorry if I was not clear about that

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a good solution for my use case which I claryfied in the question above:

1st: I wrote a Serializer that only gives me the `id` and the `name`

```
class IDNameSerializer(serializers.BaseSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return {
            'id': obj.id,
            'name': obj.name
        }
```

2nd: I wrote a view that gives me the required json response with the help of the `@api-view` decorator from django-rest-framework

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['GET'])
def tree_select(request):
    result = {}
    result['treelifephases'] = IDNameSerializer(TreeLifephase.objects.all(),many=True).data
    result['treewidths'] = IDNameSerializer(TreeWidth.objects.all(),many=True).data
    return Response(result)
```

Why I chose this as an answer:

- Through use of [@api_view](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view) decorator, we can still use permission classes and other sugar
- It gives the json response in the required format
- It is easy to alter when new fields might come there is only the view to be changed
- I don't need a django model only for serialization
- It is simple!